# Bash script working in command line but not through PHP

Tags: php, bash, imagemagick

I'm attempting to run the following command through PHP:

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo /Users/Derk/Code/automation/psc/pdfs.sh 1');
```

This runs the following bash script code:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pdftk cvcheck_template.pdf fill_form data.fdf output output.pdf flatten    
sudo /usr/local/bin/convert -density 150 -gravity south -geometry +0+150 -composite output.pdf signature.png new_output.pdf
```

The bash script works perfectly in the command line but when I attempt to run it via PHP on a web server (MAMP) it does not give me any output. The first command seems to work but the second command gives me nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you chaining `sudo`? First to run the script, and then the script apparently also runs `sudo`. Once is enough... Is the PHP being executed from the shell, or from a webserver? If the latter, check the webserver error log.

Comment: The PHP is being run through a webserver (MAMP). I checked the PHP error log but it does not show anything unfortunately. Could it be a user permissions issue?

Comment: You could create a logfile somewhere, e.g. `/tmp/debuglogfile` and make it writeable by all: `chmod 666 /tmp/debuglogfile`. Then change the PHP code to `shell_exec('sudo /Users/Derk/Code/automation/psc/pdfs.sh 1 2>/tmp/debuglogfile')` and see if any error output is written to the logfile. As you write the first command is executed (make sure it is! "seems to work" doesn't cut it), then `sudo` is apparently set up correctly, so permissions shouldn't be the problem... does the user under which the webserver runs have the same sudo rights as you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ultimately came down to a permissions issue. The individual files touched through running Python scripts through the web browser need to have write access in the www-data group.

My mistake was that they had read and execution rights but no writing rights. So once I chmodded the appropriate files everything worked beautifully.

I also used `sudo -u www-data command` to test the PHP files without having to test them through the browser. That made testing a lot faster.